# GraphQL Shopify query and sorting

Tags: graphql, shopify

We currently have a setup where customers can sort products on price, title, created, manual, etc. Every time there's a query like

```js
`query ($handle: String!, $numProducts: Int!, $sortKey: ProductCollectionSortKeys!, $reverse: Boolean!) {
  collectionByHandle(handle: $handle) {
    id
    handle
    description
    descriptionHtml
    title
    image {
      id
      originalSrc
      altText
    }
    products(first: $numProducts, sortKey: $sortKey, reverse: $reverse) {
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        hasPreviousPage
      }
      edges {...
`
```

There are 8 queries in total, one for each sortKey. The idea is to move the sorting logic to js, making a single query instead of 8.

The problem is, I can only do 7 types of sorting in javascript (PRICE, TITLE, CREATED (ascending and descending)), and either MANUAL or BEST_SELLING.
To get both MANUAL and BEST_SELLING, I currently will have 2 queries, which is already an improvent!
Is there a way to combine them into a single query, a bit like mySql, creating a 'virtual' field e.g. manual_sort_position: 5 to add to a product?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. First you speak of 8 queries. Then you say you can only do 7, and finally you ask if you can combine a GET with a mutation to CREATE? 
Please rephrase your question to be clearer.

Comment: @DavidLazar, I've just edited the post, hope it makes more sense. I'm a total newbie to both graphql and shopify.

Comment: I doubt you can combine them. Seems like you are condemned to ask for two versions of the listing, and deal with combining the results before presentation.